# Message about no longer required packages on every install through apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management

I ran this command `sudo apt-get install tor-browser` and I got this output. Should I apply autoremove as mentioned?

```
 sudo apt-get install tor-browser
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-22
      linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic
      linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
      linux-image-extra-4.4.0-22-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-21-generic
      linux-signed-image-4.4.0-22-generic
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      tor-browser
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
    Need to get 69.5 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 69.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 tor-browser amd64 6.0.2-1~webupd8~0 [69.5 MB]
```

Comment: Your "problem" has nothing to do with a browser, you would get those messages for every package you install through `apt-get`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a previous apt operation, your Linux Kernel and associates has been updated and the old kernel is not needed anymore. That's why apt system suggests you to remove the old one. You can remove them with "sudo apt autoremove" command - as suggested - after you have finished with your tor-browser installation.